# convert from polar to rectangular in scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to convert from polar to rectangular, I write this code

```
(define (polar_to_rectangular h r)
  (cons
     (* (sin (DegreesToRadians h)) r) 
     (* (cos (DegreesToRadians h)) r)
  )
 )
```

but I have this error 
cons: second argument must be a list, but received #i4.999999999999999 and #i8.660254037844387

the result is correct but still got the error 
any help please!!

Comment: sorry forget to mention I already defined (define 
(DegreesToRadians degrees)
(* degrees (/ pi 180)) 
)

Comment: Tangential, but please try to keep your naming conventions consistent. For the sake of your TA's sanity. Usually people like `to-use-this-one`.

Comment: in next time I will :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using DrRacket. The error reported happens because the teaching language in use doesn't allow to pass a non-list as the second parameter of `cons`. Use a `list` instead:

```
(define (polar_to_rectangular h r)
  (list
     (* (sin (DegreesToRadians h)) r) 
     (* (cos (DegreesToRadians h)) r)))
```

Or if you definitely have to use `cons`, then in the bottom-left corner of the window select "Determine language from source" and write this line at the beginning of the file:

```
#lang racket
```

Comment: yes I'm using DrRacket..aha,that make seance now but output still not like what I want <(cons #i4.999999999999999 (cons #i8.660254037844387 empty))>

Comment: great,,, when using #lang racket it's work thanks buddy